# Autofill Syntax not working when running VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have recorded the macro in Excel where it is working fine. The code in Excel looks like below:

```
'Setting Planned Work
Range("C14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-R[-3]C"
Range("C14").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C14:M14")
```

Below is a section of code in MS Project for VBA where I am trying to autofill in Excel. The code works up to line where it writes formula. The last line doesn't produce any result. I have attached a snapshot for reference.

Note References to Excel are working as I can see results in Excel.

```
Dim PTOutput As Excel.Worksheet
'Step6: Setting Planned Work
PTOutput.Range("C14").Select
PTOutput.Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-R[-3]C"
PTOutput.Range("C14").AutoFill Destination:=PTOutput.Range("C14:M14")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What about just using `PTOutput.Range("C14:M14").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-R[-3]C"` ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to `SET` your `PTOutput` variable to be a _particular_ worksheet, before you start referencing it?

Comment: Try:  `b = PTOutput.Range("C14").AutoFill (Destination:=PTOutput.Range("C14:M14"))` where b is declared as a Boolean.  But really, Tim’s solution is best.

Comment: Hi Tim: Your solution is working.